# How can I cu a heart-shape out of wainscoating that has been nailed together?

Tags: powertools

I am in the process of trying to figure out how to cut out a heart shape from wainscoting that has been nailed together.  I want to leave the nailed wainscoting in tact. What power tool should I use?

Comment: A bit more info would be helpful. Are you trying to cut wainscoting that is on a wall or has been removed from a wall? If it is free standing, what is it attached to? Do you want the heart to be made of wainscoting or to be a heart shaped void in the wainscoting?

Comment: 2 large drilled holes and a multi-master would keep the wall behind the wainscoting intact to a degree, if you do not wish to remove the wainscoting from the wall. Some damage will occur to the wall the wainscoting covers, it is inevitable. A sketch later...

Comment: Make sure the wainscoting will not vibrate and try some putting some tape over the areas where you drill to prevent tearout.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of care will be needed to create this, but it can be done.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The most likely tool to be used for this would be a saw of the type pictured below:

[image]

Note: Not trying to recommend any particular brand of saber saw. There are many available in a range of prices. Obviously like anything else you get what you pay for and a better grade saw like one with variable speed will be nicer for use across a greater range of project work.

**Caution:** If you are trying to cut the hole in the wainscoting that is mounted onto a wall then great care needs to be taken when cutting the hole through as the saw could cut electrical wiring, plumbing, vent pipes and sewer lines that may be in the wall. So obviously the best thing would be to have the wainscoting assembly laid out flat on a supporting surface such as a couple of saw horses with some flat 2x4's laid across the top.